# Error while invoking method through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Following are the two cases of Methods which I invoke using reflection

```
actualoutput = mgenerateouput.invoke(outputclassinst,obj);
```

`obj` is `Object` array Type which contains `Section` Type object in `obj[0]`

**Case 1:**

```
public Student[] expectedOutputString(Section sec){
        //Object arra[] = Section.makeSection((String[])params[0]);
        ReportCard rc = new ReportCard();
        Student[] exOut = rc.orderClass(sec);
        return exOut;
    }
```

it's working in first case perfect but in second case below when i declare parameter type as `Object` i get `IllegalArgumentException`.

**Case 2:**

```
public Student[] expectedOutputString(Object params[]){
    //Object arra[] = Section.makeSection((String[])params[0]);
    ReportCard rc = new ReportCard();
    Student[] exOut = rc.orderClass((Section)params[0]);
    return exOut;
}
```

[

Comment: it should be in case 2     rc.orderClass((Section)params[0]); not Second

Comment: actualoutput = mgenerateouput.invoke(outputclassinst,obj);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 2 does not declare the parameter as Object but as Object[], i.e. array of objects. So your obj[0] must be an array of objects, too.
*Edit:* Or the other way around: Code 2 should expect an Object instead of Object[].

Comment: [Answer to deleted comment] I'm not sure how this is handled in reflection method calling. I had expected that to throw a NullPointerException right away. But even if this is handled an `null` is passed to the actual method, accessing params[0] on a null array throws a NPE. And IndexOutOfBoundsException (?) on an empty array.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch, still got the same issue

Comment: Have you tried to pass a Section[] with just one element by any chance? ;) See my edit, you probably rather want to remove the `[]` from `params[]`, so that Code 1 expects one parameter of type Section and Code 2 expects one parameter of type Object. I don't see any reason why that shouldn't work with the same invocation code...

Comment: I'm just invoking a method with parameter Object[] and method signature is also expecting Object[] , what i understand is it should work , no matter whether it has one element or more .

Comment: Code 1 takes a *single* Section, Code 2 takes an *array of Object* as parameter. `Method.invoke`s second parameter is Object... of *all* parameters to the method. Your method takes one parameter and this is taken from obj[0], which is of type Section, unless you change the invoking code. Special case here is that you're passing an Object[] to Object..., which is unwrapped, even though in case 2 you don't want it to be. Try casting to Object: `method.invoke(instance, (Object) obj)`. Or wrapping in a one element Object[].

Comment: According to documentation 
Invoke Method function Signature is following
public Object invoke(Object obj,
                     Object[] args)

which state that object array args is seen as a parameter collection not as separate parameter,
when i pass Obj[] in case , It wrapped it up and pass only single element to  Object Params[] which is declared a Object Array type Not as Single Object , Which throws IAE

Comment: Java 1.4 Object[]: <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html>, Java 1.5+ Object...: <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html> The idea that the array of Object is the whole list of parameters to the actually invoked method stayed the same, with 1.5 and varargs it just became easier to use Method.invoke when the number of parameters is fixed. Other than that: yes, that's what I was trying to explain. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could be a typo:

```
rc.orderClass((Section)params[0]);  // was: Second
               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: it is section only, sorry made it second in typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

Why not using variable parameters in Case 2? 
Like:

```
public Student[] expectedOutputString(Object ... params){
```